# Adding button makes camera preview not display

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I have an app that has a camera preview view. I've added a button that overlays the FrameLayout that the camera preview is inside. Before I added the button the camera preview worked fine; however, after the addition of the button, the camera preview does not display.

Here is the xml layout I am using:

```
    >
</FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    >
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Freeze"
        android:id="@+id/buttonFreeze"
        android:background="@null"
        android:clickable="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My onClick listener and the corresponding methods:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonFreeze) {
        if(buttonFreeze.getText().equals("Freeze")) {
            mirrorView.freezePreview();
            buttonFreeze.setText("Unfreeze");
        } else {
            mirrorView.unfreezePreview();
            buttonFreeze.setText("Freeze");
        }
    }

}

public void freezePreview() {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
}

public void unfreezePreview() {
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

Is it the addition of the button that is causing this? or is it something else?

Comment: Why you use the LinearLayout? Comment it and put the button on bottom|horizontal

Comment: put linear layout in frame-layout and set gravity bottom.show your xml properly,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
if(v == buttonFreeze) {
```

with

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonFreeze) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
yourbutton.setonclickListener(this);
```